# Setting @OneToOne relationship from Doctrine entity to legacy user table

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to establish @OneToOne relationship in Doctrine entity to a "raw" database user table?

I have a legacy PHP Codeigniter 2 application that uses simple `users` table to store user data. Of course it has an `id` primary key. But there is no User entity in the app. I can't have an idea how one can establish relationship from Doctrine entity since we need to provide `targetEntity` attribute to @OneToOne annotation.

Is it legal to create "fake" User class-entity and point it to `users` table?